# Fancyhdr and Makeidx

Tags: header-footer, indexing, makeindex

Why doesn't the index have the same header/footer as the entire document? Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,imakeidx,lipsum}      
\makeindex

\lhead{Lorem Ipsum}
\rhead{Cicero}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

   \section{Lorem Ipsum}
   \index{lorem}
   \lipsum[1]

   \subsection{Nam dui Lingua}
   \index{nam}
   \lipsum[2]

   \printindex 
\end{document}
```

I have been playing around with `\indexsetup{othercode={...}}` but I haven't managed to get anywhere. I can't find anything helpful in the [documentation](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/base/makeindx.pdf) either. I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: If I change `\usepackage{lipsum}` into `\usepackage[index]{kantlipsum}` and the document body into `\kant[1-200] \printindex`, I get the expected headers on the second page of the index. Do you need them also on the first page?

Comment: @egreg I was actually suspecting that may be it, but I didn't know of a way to get the index to be longer than one page apart from adding manual entries! Seeing as the style of the index heading is similar to that of a section, I think it makes sense that the usual header/footers apply too (even on the first page). Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: Yes, but you were looking to the wrong manual.

Comment: @egreg What do you mean? Where should I have been looking?

Comment: The manual of `imakeidx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first page of the index uses page style plain. You can modify it with `\indexsetup`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,imakeidx}
\usepackage[index]{kantlipsum}

\makeindex
\indexsetup{firstpagestyle=fancy}

\lhead{Lorem Ipsum}
\rhead{Cicero}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\kant[1-200]

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Anticipated my follow up question. Excellent, thank you!